# How can I stop Extbase 6.1 blow up my deprecation log file?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have TYPO3 6.1.x system running. I have several own extensions using extbase. Now, Extbase logs insanely much deprecated function calls. How can I stop this? My deprecation log file reaches 1 GB in size in about 1 or 2 days.

Answer (score 6):

In theory, the deprecation logs are considered very helpful to developers-it should be enabled *while* developing extensions and migrating TYPO3 core versions.

To actually disable the deprecation log, you have 2 options:

1. You can either set the relevant flag via the install-tool: `enableDeprecationLog`
2. You can add the following to your `AdditionalConfiguration.php`
   `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enableDeprecationLog'] = '';`

For a quick reference, have a look at the [TYPO3 wiki page](http://wiki.typo3.org/Deprecation_Log).

Despite being enabled or not; you can always safely remove the deprecation log files.

Comment: This disables the deprecation log for all extensions at once. Okay. But is it possible, to deactivate it per extension?

Comment: Not as far as I know. If your extensions spam it, clean them :)
Should be disabled in Production anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable per ext as Cedric wrote, anyway I'd like to mention other thing: most of deprecated methods of TYPO3 API has newer version so you should consider fixing your code (de facto in most cases that's quite fast process). If you are using some modern IDE it will hint you that method is deprecated and will suggest you new one via the `typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/LegacyClassesForIde.php` class - preview it.

For an instance

`t3lib_div::_GET('foo');`
becomes:
`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('foo');`
(or `GeneralUtility::_GET('foo');` when u use imports)

Get in mind that these classes are **removed** in version 7.0 of TYPO3